# Expanding Windows Environment Variables in Filepaths

Tags: vba, windows, path, environment-variables, user-defined-functions

## Background

I am developing a VBA library of functions, for Excel on Windows, that are very useful for navigating the file system and its metadata.  I wish to include a function `Path_Expand()`, which expands every `%EnvironmentVariable%` embedded in a filepath.  So the formula

```swift
= Path_Expand("%OneDrive%\Folder\file.ext")
```

will yield the value

```
C:\Users\greg\OneDrive - My Company\Folder\file.ext
```

## Issue

I have explored the `WScript.Shell` object, with its [`.ExpandEnvironmentStrings()`](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/c1c1f29c-2a30-46a1-bae7-c17f8af55a19.asp) method.  However, the documentation stipulates that

> The ExpandEnvironmentStrings method expands environment variables defined **in the PROCESS environment space only**.

If relevant variables exist *outside* the Process environment, I fear I must build a parser, which would

- split a path into its components; then
- within each component, replace every `%Variable%` with the result from [`VBA.Environ`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/environ-function)`("Variable")`; and finally
- rejoin the components into a single path.

Obviously, I would prefer a native solution like `.ExpandEnvironmentStrings()`, so long as it is comprehensive.

## Questions

1. What environment variables (if any) are available to `Environ()`, yet unavailable to `.ExpandEnvironmentStrings()`?
2. How performant are these two functions *at scale*?
3. In light of **2.**, would it be worthwhile to cache the environment values like so

   ```vb
   Private Function GetEnvVars() As Collection
       Const MIN_I As Integer = 1, MAX_I As Integer = 255, VAR_SEP As String = "="
       Static vars As Collection, isInit As Boolean

       ' Initialize the collection as necessary...
       If Not isInit Then
           Set vars = New Collection

           ' Split and store the name and value of each variable.
           Dim str As String, strs As Variant

           For i = MIN_I To MAX_I
               str = VBA.Environ(i)

               If str = Empty Then
                   Exit For
               End If

               strs = VBA.Split( _
                   expression := VBA.Environ(i), _
                   delimiter := VAR_SEP, _
                   limit := 2 _
               )

               vars.Add Key := strs(0), Item := strs(1)
           Next i

           ' ...and record that initialization.
           isInit = True
       End If

       Set GetEnvVars = vars
   End Function
   ```

   and then retrieve them like so?

   ```vb
   GetEnvVars().Item("OneDrive")
   GetEnvVars().Item(18)
   ```

   **Or are these variables liable to change while the program runs**, and must we thus call `Environ("Variable")` anew, whenever we expand a `%Variable%`?

Comment: (A1) None. (A2) Fast enough you would have to use a millisecond timer to measure the execution time. (A3) Any caching you do will only slow things down. You seem to have a misunderstanding of how environment variables work. Each process gets a private copy of the env vars. Usually a copy of the parent process env vars but the parent process can also give the new process a different set of env vars. When an env var is modified, in say a `cmd.exe` shell, no other process will see that change.

Comment: @KurtisRader Thank you for your comment!  It is clear, concise, and germane.  :)  Feel free to post it as an answer (sources would be a plus), and I will mark it as accepted.